# Detect the rebalancing of cluster via code

Tags: java, hazelcast

Is there a way we can detect via code that the hazelcast cluster is rebalancing 
Use case: Multiple producer, multiple consumer 
Shutdown consumer1 abruptly, and see how long it takes for the other members to resume producing or consuming. In other words i am trying to see the time it takes for the cluster to rebalance.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no direct API for it.

You could write your own SPI service which receives repartitioning events.

But can you tell a bit more about your producer consumer problem? Do you want to use an IQueue for that?

Comment: yes. Producer writes to the queue and consumer reads from the queue.IT is a blocking queue i am using